# Replacing multiple null value columns with blank in tableau

Tags: datasource, tableau-api

I have data source which consist of 16 columns. Many of these columns consist of null values. I have to replace null value columns with blank (all columns at a time). 
When I surfed on internet I got one solution as create calculated field to replace null values using **IFNULL() function**. If I'll use this solution then I've to create **16 calculated fields** for **every single column**.
Is there any solution so that I can replace all null columns with blank simultaneously? Is there any GLOBAL setting which will help me to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BLANK` is the default replacement for `NULL` in Tableau.

You can set how Tableau treats `NULL`s by measure:

Right-Click the measure and select 'Format':

[image]

On the left, you will see "Special Values" section:

[image]

Set the test to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Nicarus. But this solution only worked for Measures but I want to replace Measures as well as Dimensions. This solution doesn't work for Dimensions. Can you help me to find out how to replace null values in Dimensions with blank values?

Comment: If it is a dimension, simply change the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Use LOOKUP() function, for the columns where values are present, it shows the value else blank or '-'. 
For e.g LOOKUP(SUM(Sales) , 0)
for null